# Branching the product of binary and continuous variable in Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have a binary variable (X) multiplying a continuous variable (Y). I know I can linearize by adding an auxiliary variable *(I have that model working)*, but I now want to do my own branching in the binary variable.

For what I read on Gurobi's documentation, I guess that it should be done by tightening the domain of variable X until getting to the binary solution. But I have no idea how to implement this, or even if it makes sense.

I saw [this video of Gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/events/products-of-variables-in-mixed-integer-programming/) but I think is more complex that what I need for my binary variable. And end up more confused than before.

I hope someone could guide me in how to do a branching on a binary variable in Gurobi.

Comment: You cannot tighten the domain of a binary variable - it's only either 0 or 1 and cannot be any "tighter".

Comment: I know that happens if I define it as binary in the model. But if I define it as a continuous variable, would the branching make any sense?

Comment: If it's supposed to be a binary variable, you shouldn't declare it as continuous. I don't get it.

Comment: https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Branch_and_bound_(BB)_for_MINLP